# NoClassDefFoundError on Java EE server in eclipse with tomcat

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to build a hello world application utilising GCM for Android notifications. When developing the server part, I'm not entirely sure how to get the gcm-server.jar file into the project. I've added it to the build path and Eclipse finds it perfectly fine, but when I build and deploy the project to a tomcat server (from within eclipse) it's throwing the following error at runtime:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/android/gcm/server/Sender
```

I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong when importing the jar. What exactly is the procedure for getting a jar into a dynamic web project using Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going to answer my own question because I just got it working.

Turns out adding the .jar's to the Java build path is not enough. Tomcat has a seperate classpath for each project, and won't see the classes in the jar unless you dump the jar files into the WEB-INF/lib folder (which Eclipse does not do automatically).

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the jar file for json. This question seems to have been repeated a few times.

http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/downloads/detail?name=json-simple-1.1.1.jar

Comment: Care to explain why I need to include this file? It's not mentioned at all in the GCM tutorial, and I'm not clear on why not having JSON support would cause a class not found error?

Comment: The main gcm-server.jar depends on it. It is there in their examples.

Comment: See this other query.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346180/servlet-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-json-simple-parser-parseexception

Comment: Same error after adding it, can you point me to the example you're talking about? By the way, the error is different. His error was for a missing class in the JSON thing, mine is for a missing class from gcm-server, so I'm pretty sure it's because I added it wrong (as I stated in my first post).

Comment: Sorry, not on my dev machine, but I did have the same problem and this fixed it.

Comment: If you downloaded the gcm option using the adk, then you will see a directory there like this   android-sdk-macosx/extras/google/gcm/gcm-server/lib  which has the libraries  json_simple-1.1.jar junit.jar  mockito-all-1.8.5.jar